# How to get records from last Month (not last 30 days) in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am having a part in MySQL query where I need to select the records for the last month but not the last 30 days

For example, if the current month is Jan, then I need to have the records of last month which will be Dec, but again it should show the records of Dec 2017 only and not includes previous years.

I am currently using following SQL part for the same.

```
$sql .= " AND MONTH(checkup_date) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
```

and it is showing the records for all the Decembers in database i.e Dec 2017, Dec 2016 and so on.

I even tried the following

```
$sql .= " YEAR(checkup_date) AND MONTH(checkup_date) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
```

but it will work only if last month is not earlier than Jan
i.e it will work if current month is Feb, so last month will be Jan and year will be 2018

but in my case the current month is Jan, so last month will be Dec but the year here is 2018, so it isn't and won't show any records.

So guys please help me in fixing this query so that I can get the last year in case the current month is Jan and in another case, year remains the current year.

Appreciate your help in solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query of getting all rows in a table belonging to last month in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

An alternative is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_created) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL
1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
where checkup_date < curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate())) day and
      checkup_date >= (curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate())) day) - interval 1 month
```

By not using functions on `checkup_date`, then method can take advantage of an appropriate index that h as that column.

Answer (score 0):

to get last month's

```
select DATE_ADD("2018-01-10", INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
```